# ReactJS pass function from Parent to Child throws TypeError: this.props.passedFunction is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am passing a function from Parent component to Child component. The Child component is triggering the function under certain conditions. This works correctly. But an existing test is suddenly failing.

Parent.js

```
export default class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      this.flag = false;
    }
    passedHandler = () => {
      this.flag = true;
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <Child passedFunction={this.passedHandler}/>
        </div>
      )
    }
}
```

Child.js

```
export default class Child extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    passedFunction = React.PropTypes.func
  }
  get message() {
    if(someCondition) {
      return <span>Hello</span>
    } else {
      this.props.passedFunction();
      return null;
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         {this.message}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

But I have an existing jest test that suddenly started failing after I added code to pass function from Parent to Child. It used to work before I added this code.:

test.js

```
import { data } form './test-data.js'
import {shallow, mount} from 'enzyme'

describe('Child', () => {
  test('Test something', () => {
    let { props, context } = data();
    const component = shallow(<Child {..props}/>, {context});
    expect(component.find('.someElement')).toHaveLength(0);
  }
});
```

This test throws following error:

```
TypeError: this.props.passedFunction is not a function
```

What could be wrong here? I am confused because the function does work but somehow the test fails.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say for sure as you have not provided contents of `./test-data.js`, but it seems that `props` returned by your `data` function does not contain the `passedFunction`.

**UPD:** You also have a typo as spread operator consists of three dots, while you have only two:

```
shallow(<Child {..props}/>, {context});
                 ^ Missing third dot here
```